# What do we call the spike in the cap of an ointment/cream tube?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, translation

I'm translating a text about an antifungal cream sold in aluminum tubes. The plastic cap of each tube has a spike in it used to break the foil/seal in the neck of the tube.

I'm not sure what these spikes are usually called. I googled but failed to find a description. It is **spike** or some other term?

[image]

P.S. Original in Russian:

> 15 г крема в алюминиевой запечатанной тубе с белым полиэтиленовым колпачком, имеющим **перфорационный пробойник**.
>
> Проколите  запечатывающую мембрану при помощи **острия** на внешней стороне колпачка.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

*Spike*, as you suggested, is a pretty clear term. Here is one [source about eye ointment](https://pharmasave.com/health/medication-faqs/how-to-use-an-eye-ointment/) that uses this word:

> Many tubes have a metal skin on the opening that must be pierced using the spike on the lid of the tube.

Here’s another [source about Fucidine Ointment](https://www.drugs.com/uk/fucidine-ointment-leaflet.html):

> Then push the spike
>   in the cap through the seal on the tube.

Comment: Both point and spike are easily understandable in the context.

Answer (score 19):

The one tube I have handy says:

> To Open: Remove cap, flip, and puncture safety seal.

So its completely possible to instruct in the use of the feature without having to name it directly.  For example, one doesn't need to name the threads to describe "unscrewing the cap."

Comment: I know this is not directly addressing the question asked, but OP has said they're "translating instructions" and that's exactly what this does answer.

Comment: "Turn can upside down and place **puncture tip** onto tube." – [Nystatin And Triamcinolone Acetonide](https://ndclist.com/assets/spl/images/605540d8-7189-49b9-9e91-572f6b519fae/5Y414RCC1.jpg) I'd call the OP's picture a **puncture cap**.

Comment: @Mazura that's a good answer in its own right.

Comment: I think it's colloquial though. No definition for the noun means *the thing that punctures things*. Nobody wants to have to say punctur*er* or punctur*ing* [thing].

Comment: @Mazura - please post this version as an answer

Comment: I've moved on to *piercing* (like saddle valves for ice makers; IME *punches* don't come to a point); yet another verb that doesn't like to be a noun. *Adhesive, Super Glue®, clear, **self-piercing cap**. Sold per 0.1-ounce tube.* - Note that there's a difference between a cap that has a piercer (gah), and a (self)piercing cap. One is outside and on top, and the other is inside and works when you fully screw it on, respectively.

Comment: Many punches do have a point, although they aren't always very sharp. The etymology goes back to the Latin past tense of "prick". A Google search for "definition punch" followed by clicking on Mechanics below the caption "See definitions in:" will show some pictures. I don't know how to link to that or I'd provide an answer with citation.

Comment: This is a 'comment', not a direct answer to the question. The question expressly requests a name for the 'spike', and other answers address this.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth true - but question also specifically says "translating a text" ie, instructiuons.  And while this doesn't answer the question as asked, it certainly addresses the underlying requirement of "instructions".  If you feel this answer is poor, then use downvote, that's what its for.

Comment: I feel that 19-1 upvotes for 'What do we call a "spike"? You don't need to use the actual word' on a site aimed at linguists and serious students of the language sends out a wrong message, one of mediocrity, and will make my views on the matter known.

Answer (score 17):

It can just be called a [*point*](https://www.wordnik.com/words/point).

> An object having a sharp or tapered end.

Here are a couple of label examples:

[[image: Label Instructions for using point in cap.[1]]

[image]

Comment: @Tim great **pun**ctuation there.

Comment: I find "point in top of cap"(first example) far better than "point on cap" (second example) which would lead me to expect a triangular shaped cap rather than having the point inside the cap rim

Answer (score 13):

As an alternative to **spike**, you might want to consider **[punch](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/punch)** (M-W):

> **[punch](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/punch)**: a tool usually in the form of a short rod of steel that is variously shaped at one end for different operations (such as
>   forming, perforating, embossing, or cutting)

For present purposes, the key words here are *tool*, *shaped at one end for different operations*, and *[perforating](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/perforate)*, i.e., making a hole through.

With punch, @laurel's (excellent) examples would read:

> Many tubes have a metal skin on the opening that must be pierced using
>   the **punch** on the lid of the tube.
>
> Then push the **punch** in the cap through the seal on the tube.

While I like **spike**, and might use it if I were writing instructions on how to use a tube of cream, it doesn't capture the intent of the feature under discussion as does **punch**.

Comment: 'I'm not sure what these spikes are usually called.' Just 'spikes'.

Comment: It's a *puncture*. Because it's for puncturing things. It has a purpose, and therefore a name, it's not just 'spiky' shaped.

Comment: @Mazura I didn't say that it was *'spiky' shaped*. Perhaps this comment belongs somewhere else. BTW, none of the dictionaries I've checked contain a definition of *puncture* as an object used for puncturing things.

Comment: @Mazura I would have thought the *puncture* was the hole. So perhaps *puncturer* as in [US Patent 6098795](https://patents.justia.com/patent/6098795) or, as Richard Kayser suggests, simply *punch*

Comment: The word is *punch*; the *punct**ure*** is either the process or the result of using it ("punct" for point, as in *punctuation*). c.f. *creator* vs *creature* or *eraser* vs *erasure*.

Comment: If I run the Dutch word _doorprikpunt_ through Google Translate, I get _puncture point_. Can't seem to find many examples where that phrase is used in the correct context though, so not posting an answer.

Comment: No, a punch for a hole has a cutting edge which is the shape of the hole.

Comment: There are many different types of punch. Spikes can be punches, some designed to make small circular holes, perforations.

Answer (score 3):

Converting Mazura's [comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/531711/what-do-we-call-the-spike-in-the-cap-of-an-ointment-cream-tube#comment1298707_531748) into a community answer:

> Turn can upside down and place **puncture tip** onto tube. – [Nystatin And Triamcinolone Acetonide](https://ndclist.com/assets/spl/images/605540d8-7189-49b9-9e91-572f6b519fae/5Y414RCC1.jpg)
>
> I'd call the OP's picture a **puncture cap**.

Answer (score 3):

Via Twitter:

> *Ointments/creams in sealed tubes have a small **cone** in the top of the lid that can be used to puncture the seal.*
>
> > > [image]

Source: https://twitter.com/HarkerDavid/status/1153045376938717192

[Elsewhere](https://www.bendigobowlsshop.com.au/products/grippo) the “spike” is described as a ***piercer***

> *Assists with grip and easy to apply from convenient screw cap (with piercer) tube.*

A [wholesaler](https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/Wholesale-plastic-closures-plastic-screw-caps_60499423193.html) that supplies screw caps with internal spikes describe them as a **puncture top** or **piercer**

> *Fez with puncture top (piercer)* [image]